# Not able to send mail from ubuntu 14.04 localhost to my gmail account using php laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to send email from ubuntu machine localhost but i am unable to send it from laravel i have configured mail.php file such as :

1. 'driver' => 'smtp',
2. 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
3. 'port' => 587,
4. 'from' => array('address' => 'mygmailaddress@gmail.com', 'name' => 'my name'),
5. 'encryption' => 'tls',
6. 'username' => 'my gmail account',
7. 'password' => 'my gmail account password',
8. 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

and in php.ini file setting is such as :

```html
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path =  "/usr/bin/sendmail -t"
```

and i have used laravel mail::send function to send email but i am gettting error message like

[image]

Comment: have you specified the host ?

Comment: in which file i need to specifiy host name is it in php.ini or laravel mail.php file ?

Comment: i have already specified 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', in laravel mail.php file. did't mentioned in question @sorry

Comment: Show us the code how you are sending this e-mail

Comment: @NirmalKumar You don't have to change `php.ini` to send email from Laravel. And don't use gmail password directly, gmail will provide you a code to use in apps and devices instead of your original password.

Comment: Mail::send('event.mailview', array('key' => 'value'), function($message)
{
 $message->to('anygmailid@gmail.com', 'any name')->subject('Welcome To my project ');
  });
  
  if( count(Mail::failures()) > 0 ) {
      echo "There was one or more failures. They were: <br />";
  }
  else{
   echo "Mail Sent";
  }

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek above is code to send mail from my controller file.